# Vagrant shell commands aren't being run on the guest OS box

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, vagrant

I have the following Vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
        printf "\n\nClientAliveInterval 3\nClientAliveCountMax 2" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        service ssh restart
    SHELL
end
```

It runs just fine but when I view the contents of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` the changes I made to it aren't there. BUT when I do `printf "\n\nClientAliveInterval 3\nClientAliveCountMax 2" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config` via the CLI (well, via `sudo bash`) it works just fine.

I'm running Vagrant 2.2.7 and Hyper-V with Windows 10 Version 1909.

Any ideas why the the Vagrant file isn't writing to that file?

Comment: The original poster had an answer from me, but it seems like their core issue has nothing to do with a provisioning shell command in a Vagrant file but rather SMB/CIFS errors on provisioning as shown in their [config here](https://pastebin.com/qKBxnar6) and the [output errors here](https://pastebin.com/mc3KgAUw). My recommendation is for the original poster to delete this question and post a new question about why their Vagrant file is failing with SMB errors. Because none of the content of this question relates to that.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - SMB/CIFS is typically used for file sharing. I don't care about sharing files. I suppose it's possible that you can't run commands on Hyper-V without enabling file sharing (I didn't code Vagrant so anything is possible) but that'd be annoying AF if that were the case. That's like saying that you have to run water in the sink to take a shower in the shower. I mean, that may very well be the case but in both cases it's still annoying AF and doesn't seem like it ought to be that way...

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - you're right. Here's the log when I did enter the username / password in: https://pastebin.com/4QyiaAUs Frustrating, but at least it's working - thanks!

Comment: Happy to hear! But does this mean my answer about the ways to deal with inline scripts is still valid? You seem to have two distinct issues here it seems; did my advice help your provisioning script issue?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - it seems to work fine with the inline HEREDOC.

Comment: Okay, will undelete. If you found my answer helpful, please upvote it. If my answer was the answer that solved your issue, please check it off as such.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - I think prob the most helpful bit was your last comment in your answer lol. It motivated me to look at the SMB/CIFS error and not just dismiss it out of hand as I had been doing

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way:

```
sh -c "printf '\n\nClientAliveInterval 3\nClientAliveCountMax 2' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config";
```

And if that doesn’t work, run it as sudo like this:

```
sudo sh -c "printf '\n\nClientAliveInterval 3\nClientAliveCountMax 2' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config";
```

The way I understand it is the `sh -c` will take that string in the double quotes and run it as a command. As to why it does not run without the `sh -c`… No idea. But perhaps you can take your config and just run the same command as sudo like this:

```
sudo printf "\n\nClientAliveInterval 3\nClientAliveCountMax 2" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo service ssh restart
```

And if all of that stuff still doesn’t work, the larger issue might be you trying to use “[heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)” formatting in the YAML config directly. I would recommend doing this instead:

```
$script = <<-SHELL
printf "\n\nClientAliveInterval 3\nClientAliveCountMax 2" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
service ssh restart
SHELL

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
end
```

Or you could do this instead:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "laravel/homestead"
    config.vm.provision "shell",
      inline: "printf '\n\nClientAliveInterval 3\nClientAliveCountMax 2' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config' && service ssh restart"
end
```

Read up on the [shell provisioning process for inline scripts here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell#inline-scripts) in the official Vagrant docs.

Comment: I tried each of those without success :(

Comment: See https://pastebin.com/UF9p4WSP . I'm trying to write to a different directory, too, now. Nothing. When I try to run each of those commands via the CLI...   `printf zzz > /home/vagrant/aaa.txt` works. `printf zzz > /home/vagrant/aaa.txt` gives a `sudo: printf > /home/vagrant/bbb.txt: command not found` error. `sh -c "printf > /home/vagrant/ccc.txt"` gives a `sh: 1: printf: usage: printf format [arg ...]` error as does `sudo sh -c "printf > /home/vagrant/ddd.txt"`.

Comment: @neubert I updated my answer: I think the issue is you using “heretic” formatting directly in the YAML config in the Vagrant file. I believe that will not work the way you expect it to. Look at my new edits/additions and check the link to the official Vagrant shel script provisioning docs for more info.

Comment: No such luck. My new Vagrantfile: https://pastebin.com/qKBxnar6 . My new output: https://pastebin.com/mc3KgAUw . When I SSH into the machine `/home/vagrant` is empty, in spite of my Vagrantfile.

Comment: @neubert Seems like you have issues happening here other than the provisioning script errors you mentioned above. I mean the main error I see is an SMB/CIFS error and not a “writing config options to a script” error that your question is supposedly about: “mount error(13): Permission denied. Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs).” My recommendation is for you to delete this question and post a new question about why your Vagrant file is failing with SMB errors. One single question can’t just be one massive debugging thread on this site. Will be deleting my answer now.